# Postfix mail relay to external address, SPF Check

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, spf, aliases

I have a question which is not about the configuration but about the question what is right and what not.

The scenario:
Organisation A (OrgA) has a Mailserver which is responsible for `example.org`. The Head of OrgA is also Head of Company B (CompB, `example.com`). Now the it guys from OrgA used their Postfix aliases file to forward all mails for `Head.Boss@example.org` to `Head.Boss@example.com`

Should look like this:

```
cat /etc/postfix/aliases
Head.Boss:Head.Boss@example.com
```

Now a worker of CompanyC writes an email to `Head.Boss@example.org` which gets "redirected" to `Head.Boss@example.com`. In that case the Mailserver of OrgA acts as simple mail relay, right? If CompanyC provides a SPF record and CompanyB checks this one there should be a failure because the mailserver of OrgA does not match with the SPF of the sender CompanyC.

Is it a good manner to redirect mails to external addresses like that? Or shouldn't that matter because there is no DMARC Record which tells to drop messages not matching the SPF?

Answer (score 0):

The it people at orga.com should use SRS to forward the mail. For instructions on how to set this up, see: https://jichu4n.com/posts/setting-up-dkim-and-srs-in-postfix/ .
For more information, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme

Answer (score 0):

Company B (`example.com`) should be aware that the Organization A (`example.org`) is forwarding the mail. This way the mailserver of `example.com` could be trusted to perform the SPF/DMARC checks on behalf of the mailserver of `example.org` and, thus, the SPF/DMARC checks can be omitted.

While the implementation is a technical solution, this really comes to the trust relationship between the organizations in question, as well as whether potentially confidential information about Organization A should be forwarded to and held on the servers of Company B.

Comment: But you cannot have this trust relation with _every_ company that is possible to write emails.

Comment: In the described scenario, you don't have to. Company C has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Ah, you mean a trust between OrgA und Comany B? Well that would help but if thats not the way you should forward mails you should not accept this.

Comment: Yes. If there's no such relationship between the organizations, just the same individual, the `Head.Boss` should have two mailboxes.

Comment: Okey, got you...